# network-manager won't show same SSID hotspots!

Tags: network-manager, vpn, wicd

I'm currently using WICD and it shows 4 different hotspots and their details (channel, etc). These 4 hotspots have the very same SSID. I can connect to whichever I want. So far so good. 
The thing is, I need to use a VPN so I moved back to network-manager since it's very easy to configure one with it. The problem is, I want to be able to choose which one of these hotspots I'll connect to. But since network-manager only shows one (don't know how it is chosen)...it makes everything harder.

Basically, I need to be able to see, and to choose, every single network available and not just the one NM considers the best.
OR
A way to use a VPN with WICD.

PS: If you're wondering, these are free hotspots and for some reason some are slower than others, that's why I need to connect to one in a specific channel.

Answer (score 0):

Network Manager attempts to roam for you.  It will show only one SSID even when there are many access points, then attempt to stay connected to the best one.  Access points with the same SSID should really be identical and there is no reason to prefer one over another.  Unfortunately neither Wicd or Network Manager does a perfect job of this.  Wicd doesn't try and just stays connected to the access point you pick unless it is completely hopeless.  Network Manager has some roaming logic but doesn't always get it right.

You used to be able to disable roaming from Gnome Network Admin and I can't imagine they've removed that option.  Go into connection properties and there should be a checkbox.